# Access Denied when creating task for taskscheduler using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks

I am getting Access Denied, no matter what I try, when attempting to execute the demo on

https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

which is

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? Do you run it from admin account?

Comment: The line right after "Register the task in the root folder"

Comment: Having the same problem when running as admin.  Very odd.

Comment: Might have solved mine with some visual studio magic, app manifest and disabling vs hosting process - are you still having the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator/2818776#2818776 was useful

Comment: Yes I am, It's been a minute since I tried this, Im going to pull out that code soon and see if that helps, any details on the app manifest you can offer?